# Can Open Office (or any open source database program) convert .ACCDT files to .MDB?

Tags: open-source, openoffice-base

Can Open Office (or any open source database program) convert .ACCDT files to .MDB?

This is specifically about the **template**, hence **.ACCD*T*** and not the database file **.ACCD*B***.

Tools I have available is **"MS Access 2003"**.

Researching this for a charity organisation with very limited resources.

Comment: I don't think so. But it is probably best to explain what your situation is and what you are trying to achieve, instead of asking about one possible solution.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. However, this **is** what i wanna achieve. I teach absolute beginner database classes in a resource-poor environment, and I got a got a resource of templates, seemingly tailor-made for my students but they're in the wrong format (ACCDT), not .mdb. I will try to research LibreOffice, but I don't have much hope.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is NO.

For the longer answer, I point you to this thread. [A 1st OpenOffice forum thread](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=14060)

Specifically the 4th post by user **Villeroy**
of which i am quoting here when s/he talks about the difference between OOo's database program, **Base**, and otoh, **MS Access**

> Both are database frontends, which can be used to read, display and
> possibly write several types of tabular data sources from CSV to highe
> end database servers. Access can create single-file databases from
> scratch by using the MS JET engine, Base pretends to do the same thing
> when it wraps http://hsqldb.org/ into a zip-archive. This office suite is strictly focussed (and limited) to document creation (text, spreadsheet, presentations, vector graphics with charts and mathematical formulas). Thus Base is hardly more than a bridge to import data sources regardless of file formats into office documents.

There's a bit more on a different thread:
Relevant bit:

> You can not open MSA .mdb or accdb files with Base, but you could
> connect to it, only on MS operation systems. (Base can not be
> connected to other MSA file types such as mde, mdt, **accdt**, accde
> etc.) You can reach **only** tables, queries, the forms, reports and
> coding not usable, needs to create from scratch.

However, if anyone wants to comb through this
[WIKIPAGE](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Connecting_to_Microsoft_Access#Access_to_the_Tables), they're welcome to do so, of course. It seems truly interesting but I'm afraid I've run out of time today. Thanks, all.

[A 2nd OpenOffice forum thread](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=83&t=25300)

This forces me conclude that it can't be done.
[1](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=14060)